# Remove letters from a cell leaving numbers only

Tags: excel, vba, letters

I am trying to remove all letters from a cell and leave the numbers remaining.
I have found bits of code and other questions on here but none are making much sense to me.

I have in cell E23 "as12df34" and want the value of Cell E23 to read "12 34"

Can anyone help with this query please?

Comment: `Can anyone help with this query please?` what have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you even Google for anything? There are [many](http://forum.chandoo.org/threads/removing-all-charcters-from-cell-but-numbers.13352/) [examples](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/651-excel-remove-non-numeric-characters.html).  What have you tried? What hasn't worked? I see you want to replace the letter, but keep the placeholder?

Comment: At the moment I have code that loops through every used cell in a column to perform an action (change the contents etc....). With this problem I'm having is getting the code to loop through and remove the letters from the cell leaving the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
Sub UsageExample()
  Dim cl

  ' iterate each cell
  For Each cl in Range("Sheet1!A1:A100")
    ' replace each non digit sequence by a space
    cl.Value = ReplaceRe(cl.Value, "\D+", " ")
  Next

End Sub

Public Function ReplaceRe(text As String, pattern As String, replacement) As String
  Static re As Object
  If re Is Nothing Then
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True
  End If
  re.pattern = pattern
  ReplaceRe = re.Replace(text, replacement)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a UDF if you want to do something like that. Making "Spaces" True or False will allow for you to have a single space where non-numeric characters used to be.

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Nums("as12df34", True)
End Sub

Function Nums(What As String, Spaces As Boolean) As String

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Len(What)

    If IsNumeric(Mid(What, i, 1)) = True Then Nums = Nums & Mid(What, i, 1)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(What, i, 1)) = False Then Nums = Nums & " "

Next i

Nums = Trim(Nums)

If Spaces = True Then
    Do Until InStr(Nums, "  ") = 0
        Nums = Replace(Nums, "  ", " ")
    Loop
Else
    Do Until InStr(Nums, " ") = 0
        Nums = Replace(Nums, " ", "")
    Loop
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may have been answered, but I wanted to let others that may come across this question to see another possibility. I came up with an obvious solution to eliminate all the letters to be replaced with nothing to only leave numbers in the cell. You can just replace the "" for a " " to leave the space that the letters left behind.

It's a huge clutter, but I use it and it works as intended just drag the function to the next cell. No typing required. In my situation, I had a word like "platinum ingot, 3" and it will remove all the letters, comma, and spaces and leaves 3 which can be used to calculate stuff with. I use this to hold 2 values in 1 cell when 1 of the value is never going to also contain numbers.

> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( F5,"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q",""),"R",""),"S",""),"T",""),"U",""),"V",""),"W",""),"X",""),"Y",""),"Z",""),"a",""),"b",""),"c",""),"d",""),"e",""),"f",""),"g",""),"h",""),"i",""),"j",""),"k",""),"l",""),"m",""),"n",""),"o",""),"p",""),"q",""),"r",""),"s",""),"t","") ,"u",""),"v","") ,"w",""),"x",""),"y",""),"z",""),",","")," ","")